# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un pop up desde un tabBar en swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, popup

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intento que cuando se pulse el botón verde de la tabBar, aparezca la view de este como si fuera un pop up

Comment: Puedes agregar el código que has intentado?

Comment: He intentado el codigo de esta página https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46071125/present-a-view-modally-from-a-tab-bar-controller

Comment: Cuál es el error con el código de esa respuesta?